# How to check whether my script ran successfully in crontab

Tags: unix, crontab

I am new to Unix and I need some help to know how to check whether my script has picked by crontab and ran as per schedule (not manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this by using a crontab to run the scheduled command `touch helloworld.txt`

Comment: Thanks but before that we need to use `rm helloworld.txt ` in script before touch command so that we can 100 percent tell that our script run successfully in cron tab.